# mongodb: update()/updateMany() operation finds by filter and then applies changes these two operations are atomic for one document?

Tags: mongodb

update()/updateMany() operation finds by filter and then applies changes these two operations are atomic for one document?
For example,
document has field "value" = 1, then I execute
update({"value": 1}, {"$inc": {"value": 1}})
If execute multiple update()/updateMany() operations exactly the same as above can I get value more then 2?
I found in mongo documentation that "modification of each document is atomic". But how about find and update together?

Comment: Atomic is only referred to changes, finding has nothing to do with it.
It means as soon as some document is found to match, it is atomically changed

Comment: So in my example value can have value more then 2?

Comment: no it can not, it is found, then blocked, updated and won't appear again in any updateMany() calls on value:1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.